# angular click event share to other click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have two links using AngularJS ng-click, they both have the same on click event by pass same scope variable.

```
ui.myclick(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3)

<a ng-click="ui.myclick(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3)">link1</a>

<a ng-click="ui.myclick(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3)">link2</a>
```

Is it possible to define the on click handler somewhere in HTML so I could reuse it? Like this:

```
ng-init="var commonclick = ui.myclick(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3)"
```

Then my ng-click would be just:

```
<a ng-click="commonclick">Link1</a>
<a ng-click="commonclick">Link2</a>
```

Comment: No that is not a syntax that is available for `ng-click`, also I wouldn't recommend this anyways. Your controller is exactly where you want to handle event logic, or inside a directive, if you were using one.

Comment: Please imrpove your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the function in your controller and use it on the ng-click attribute, like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as m">
    <a ng-click="m.f(arg)">Link 1</a>
    <a ng-click="m.f(arg)">Link 2</a>
</div>
<script>
    angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.f = function(arg) {
                console.log(arg);
            }
        }])
    ;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it the way you are trying to do. The hindrance is that you can't use `bind` method or `function` which you could use to create a function in ngInit. There are however at least two workarounds I can think of.

**1. Helper factory** in controller.

```html
<div ng-init="commonclick = createFunction(ui.myclick, myVar1, myVar2, myVar3)">...</div>
```

where `createFunction` is defined in controller as:

```
$scope.createFunction = function(fn) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(null, args);
    };
};
```

Then you will be able to use `commonclick` as

```
<a ng-click="commonclick()">Link1</a>
<a ng-click="commonclick()">Link2</a>
```

**#2. Event delegation**. For some cases you can benefit from `onclick` even bubbling. In this case, you would attach only one ngClick directive to parent element and it will handle all child events:

```
<div ng-click="ui.myclick(myVar1, myVar2, myVar3)">
    <a>Link1</a>
    <a>Link2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to make your markup as clean as possible, you can have a combination of setting `ng-click` as a function using and `ng-repeat`

**Markup:**

```
<a ng-repeat="link in links" ng-click="clickFunction(link)">{{link}}</a>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('Main Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.links = ['Link1', 'Link2']; //define links

    $scope.clickFunction = function(value) {
        //define what clickFunction does
    }
})
```